# Django FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Users\\ivan\\Desktop\\Python\\static'

Tags: python, django, collectstatic

I'm trying to install django debug toolbar to track ORM queries to the database.
Got this erorr

```
WARNINGS:
?: (debug_toolbar.staticfiles.W001) debug_toolbar requires the STATICFILES_DIRS directories to exist.
        HINT: Running manage.py collectstatic may help uncover the issue.
```

Decided to run python manage.py collectstatic and getting the error
Here's the settings files.

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    #...
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    #..
    'debug_toolbar',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    #...
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware', 
]

# ...

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': str(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "db.sqlite3")),
    }
}


# ....

STATIC_URL='/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS =[
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static').replace("\\", "/"),
]
```

Comment: I tihnk don't need of replace method in  `STATICFILES_DIRS ` Just use `os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')`

Comment: I didn't use it before. it didn't work anyway

Comment: Is `DEBUG` equal to `False` in `settings.py`??? If yes and you are running django with `runserver`, then no need to do `collectstatic`, which is for deployment.
You'd better create a `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')` in your `settings.py` too.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. In your project's root directory, create a new directory called `static_files`. It should be alright now that that directory exists, and it seems to be needed because debug_toolbar queries that folder for files, for some reason without first checking whether the folder exists or not.